# Service Fabric Process Monitoring

Tags: azure-service-fabric, process-monitoring

I have hosted microservices  and background processes (stateless) on the service fabric cluster of 5 nodes.

The query is specific to the process monitoring - as the single node could have  multiple processes running and you get the aggregate monitoring metrics. I would like to get the metrics specific to the processes rather than aggregated.
Below is the example - which gives the processes running on each node and % specific to it.

Example
  1 Node 1         Process 1          process%
  2 Node 1         Process 2          process%
  3.Node 2         Process 1          process%

One of the approach to run one process- watcher to monitor these jobs, any other approach or out of box feature to get these details? Thanks much

Comment: Sorry if I didn't get the question but are you talking about having this per process information on the Service Fabric dashboard or obtaining this information in general?

Answer (score 0):

If the services are running in Exclusive process mode, they map to a single process on each machine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-hosting-model#exclusive-process-model. In this case using Performance counters if Windows or top on Linux to monitor the process that hosts the service would be an option. To get the process name of a specific instance/replica using this Service Fabric api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-model-codepackageentrypoint

Answer (score 0):

You can collect [performance metrics for specific processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-common-scenarios#how-can-i-monitor-performance-counters) and view them in perfmon or export them to Log Analytics or another tool to aggregate all your diagnostics.

The link above shows these two examples for processes in the [.NET quickstart app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-dotnet)

- .NET CLR Memory(VotingData)\\# Total committed Bytes
- .NET CLR Memory(VotingWeb)\\# Total committed Bytes